# Managing the "DNS Zone Template" in Plesk / Parallels 11.0.9

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record

I have a (dv) Dedicated Virtual hosting environment running Plesk 11 at Media Temple. I am able to control the Default DNS Zone Template used to create new virtual hosts as I add customers.

Forgive my naivety, but my question is: do I need the NS, A and AAAA records for `ns.<domain>.` in the template? None of my customers will be running their own name servers at `NS.<domain>`. BUT I have configured BIND/named to use private name servers for my master domain (NS and NS2.MYDOMAIN.COM). Will removing them from the template, interfere?

**My default template has the following records:**

```
Host    Record type Value
<domain>.           NS      ns.<domain>.    #needed?
<domain>.           A       <ip>
<domain>.           AAAA    <ipv6>
<domain>.           MX      (10)    mail.<domain>.
<domain>.           TXT     v=spf1 +a +mx -all
<ip> / 24           PTR     <domain>.
<ipv6> / 64         PTR     <domain>.
ftp.<domain>.       CNAME   <domain>.
ipv4.<domain>.      A       <ip>
ipv6.<domain>.      AAAA    <ipv6>
mail.<domain>.      A       <ip>
mail.<domain>.      AAAA    <ipv6>
ns.<domain>.        A       <ip>            #needed?
ns.<domain>.        AAAA    <ipv6>          #needed?
webmail.<domain>.   A       <ip>
webmail.<domain>.   AAAA    <ipv6>
```

I appreciate your insight, thanks.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk works in cooperation with a DNS server, which enables you to run DNS service on the same machine. The DNS zones are primaly *slave zones*. You will need to configure your main zone with an asterisk `*` poinitng to your server ip address.

- `AAAA` DNS record type for IPv6 - If you have no IPv6 services enabled, you don't need those entries.
- `NS` DNS record type for name servers - the entry reflects your internal mail services (a simple stupid performance booster for postfix or qmail).

You can find more information about record types [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types).

Also, as a side note, if you *don't know* what you are doing **never change a dns zone manually**.